# Simple flow for a Component Test

Tags: karate

How to write a component test for a web service using karate? => Loading dependent data with mock servers and then request to original service.

Hopefully the following url helps,
https://gist.github.com/PavanKumarReddy/44323e294d8055f7cb6959db31c3afec

Around this

```
#set up mock dependencies: where should this code be placed ?
    And eval map['mockResponse1'] = mockResponse1
    And eval map['mockResponse2'] = mockResponse2
#end of set up
```

Comment: as the author of Karate I find this question very hard to read and understand. you say many things and ask many different questions. can you simplify your question to just one or two things and ask separate questions if needed ? try using examples, thanks.

Comment: edited the question, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I think you have Karate client-side and server-side confused and your example has mock-like stuff until line 15 where it becomes a client-side test !

Anyway I think you need to read this article very carefully and it should answer all your questions: [API Consumer-Contract Tests and Test-Doubles with Karate](https://hackernoon.com/api-consumer-contract-tests-and-test-doubles-with-karate-72c30ea25c18).

Specifically:

> set up mock dependencies: where should this code be placed ?

Typically from your JUnit test, by calling the API to start mocks. The mock feature files can init data via a variety of ways. You can pass parameters into it via a bunch of variables in a java `Map`.

Comment: Not exactly Confused !! Intentional Experiment.  I have gone through the documentation. I believe the ones which you are referring to are 'Contract Testing' am looking for an example of 'Component Testing' with a simpler interface/approach. As deleted context in original question as it's causing confusion. I can achieve this by using Java interop or if there is a way i can mutate global variables. PS: Terminology referred from here : https://martinfowler.com/articles/microservice-testing/

Comment: @pavankumarreddy after all these years I admit I have no idea what this so-called "Component Testing" is :) For me the row #(4) in the diagram is component testing. sounds like you want everything magically done for you without writing any code :P all the best !

Comment: :) not obsessed with the naming here, thought it would convey the idea easily. Since am new, just want to confirm if there is any other easy way. I might be over optimistic here :P. Thanks !!!